# SQL database text field values show as strange char

Tags: sqlite, encode

ǀǿɄǿȸȗȾȋȵļȅȩȦȸǿȗȦļƥǿȠȅȗȻȣļǌȩȠɇȅǿȲȂȩȬȔȗȠļžŲŻȣȑ !

I have an sqlite table with too many fields, all of them shows correctly except for one text field.
It looks like text above. Although text is actually English.
Is this an encoding problem ? Can I fix it anyhow ?

Comment: Yes, this is an encoding problem in the code that writes and/or reads this field. (Which you have not shown.)

Comment: @CL. it looks like this when i open database directly not using any code. "using sqlite 3 database on windows".

Comment: Some program wrote the data. Some program opened the database.